# IntegrityError when loading auth.user and profile models in Django fixtures

Tags: python, django, fixtures

I'm trying to create some fixtures to use for running tests in Django. Right now, I'm just dumping the appropriate models from my dev db and then loading those through the test. Here's the command I use to dump the fixtures:

```
python manage.py dumpdata accounts.Profile auth.User -n auth.User --indent 4 -e contenttypes > path/to/fixture.json
```

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942214/django-loading-users-using-inital-data-json?lq=1) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447214/integrityerror-when-loading-fixture-during-django-testing?lq=1) I've added flags for using natural keys and excluding content types. This doesn't help -- I get this error message:

```
IntegrityError: Could not load accounts.Profile(pk=1): duplicate key value violates unique constraint "accounts_profile_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) already exists
```

I've check the fixture manually and there is only one entry for that user id. The Profile model is pretty standard, with some extra fields with personal information. It's linked to User in the model with the following:

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

In the name of completeness, here's what the fixtures look like:

```
{
    "pk": 1, 
    "model": "auth.user", 
    "fields": {
        "username": "unique_username", 
        "first_name": "", 
        "last_name": "", 
        "is_active": true, 
        "is_superuser": true, 
        "is_staff": true, 
        "last_login": "2013-03-31T23:19:44.391", 
        "groups": [], 
        "user_permissions": [], 
        "password": "secret",
        "email": "email", 
        "date_joined": "2013-03-13T21:30:39.225"
    }
},
{
    "pk": 1, 
    "model": "accounts.profile", 
    "fields": {
        "status": "active", 
        "first_name": "John", 
        "last_name": "Smith", 
        "middle_name": null, 
        "headline": "Something very cool", 
        "user": [
            "unique_username"
        ], 
        "location": null
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Is it because of the hook I use to link User and Profile?

I'm running Django 1.4 using the Enthought distro of Python 2.6, on Mac OS X (10.7.5).

Answer (score 11):

This often happens with OneToOneFields() if you have:

Profile.user = models.OneToOneField(User) when django creates User records it automatically creates Profiles for these users (probably via post_save). So when loaddata starts to import Profiles, each User already has a profile and additional profiles break the constraint.

I had 2 models pointing to User via OneToOneField:

- Profiles;
- Calendar.

To fix the issue:

1) export auth.user into a separate auth_user.json;

```
./manage.py dumpdata --indent=4 auth.user > auth_user.json
```

2) export other models:

```
./manage.py dumpdata --indent=4 -e sessions -e admin -e contenttypes -e auth.Permission --natural-foreign > other_models.json
```

3) load User records:
./manage.py loaddata auth_user

4) open `./manage.py shell`
or `shell_plus`
and delete all the Profiles and Calendar records:

```
Profiles.objects.all().delete()
Profiles.objects.all().count()
Calendar.objects.all().delete()
Calendar.objects.all().count()
```

5) load the rest of the records:

```
./manage.py loaddata other_models
```

Comment: This got me most of the way to fixing my problem, but I ended up just commenting out the code that automatically creates the associated `Profile` when adding or saving a User, ran the `loaddata` command, and then uncomment it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

When using `OneToOneField` you probably have defined a `post_save` signal. So when the User is created the `post_save` signal that follows creates the Profile and when `loaddata` attempts to create the corresponding Profile it was already created by the `post_save` signal. The simplest thing to do is to comment out the `post_save` signals in your code just to execute `loaddata`.

Comment: Yes! Just add `if kwargs['raw']: return` to the signal handler (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#what-s-a-fixture)

Comment: Denis, your comment should be and answer by itself. This is the best solution IMO

Answer (score 2):

This may not an offtopic, but since Google points here o similar problem with loading fixtures with eg. `contenttypes.ContentType` im inclined to help.

Use [natural keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/serialization/#natural-keys) to avoid duplicate key value violations when data changes it's primary keys.

Add [`--natural-foreign`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-dumpdata--natural-foreign) option during dumpdata, eg.:

```
$ python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign contenttypes auth.Permission auth.Group
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem.  In my case I confirmed that the database row for User id=1 did not exist (via User.objects.all()).

In my case it turned out that I was loading two fixtures:

- initial_preferences.json (custom user preferences)
- initial_admin_user.json

The preferences fixture model has a ForeignKey reference to a User.  If I load preferences first, I get the duplicate key error, even though there is still no User id=1.

Swapping the order to load the admin_user before preferences fixed the issue for moe.

So -- check to see if you have already created other model objects that have a reference to User id=1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to load fixtures into a DB that already contains those rows, so it' raising an `IntegrityError`. You could drop the tables before running the `loaddata`, but really the fixtures should only be used to initially populate the table.

Comment: Does the Django test db already contain all the data? I thought, probably incorrectly, that the only data in the test db is what I include in the fixture.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Postgres database?

I ran into similar issue with loading fixtures and having Postgres as my database. Auto increment sequences were not set to the values they were supposed to be set.

This post helped me: https://www.vlent.nl/weblog/2011/05/06/integrityerror-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint/