# Django dumpdata/loaddata – Key is not present in table

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I'm trying to dump my postgres data and load it locally, but I'm ending up with an error

These are my two models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True
    )
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

This is the code I'm executing for the data dump:

```
call_command('dumpdata', indent=4, exclude=['contenttypes', 'auth.Permission', 'sessions', 'admin.logentry'])
```

However, when trying to load it, I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixtures: insert or update on table "profiles_profile" violates foreign key constraint "profiles_profile_user_id_a3e81f91_fk_accounts_user_id"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) is not present in table "accounts_user".
```

What I noticed when trying to read the fixture is that there are no pks for the user, and no references from the profile:

```
{
    "model": "accounts.user",
    "fields": {
        "password": "xyz",
        "last_login": "2022-11-27T17:28:45.854Z",
        "is_superuser": true,
        "username": "JohnDoe",
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "is_staff": true,
        "is_active": true,
        "date_joined": "2020-09-02T16:28:13.329Z",
        "groups": [],
        "user_permissions": []
    }
},

{
    "model": "profiles.profile",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "dob": "1980-06-20",
    }
},
```

Is that normal? Note that I also tried using the natural-foreign and natural-primary-keys arguments in the call_command as well, without any effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *also tried using natural-foreign and natural-primary-keys like this:* <you've pasted the same call_command again here>. Is it important to you to move the data this way, or have you considered dumping it using `pg_dump` and then restoring with `pg_restore` locally? You can even pipe pg_dump directly to psql: `pg_dump -h target_db_host -p 5432 -U username dbname | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -U username dbname`

Comment: there might be pk field in dump json. Ca you  try to run dumpdata command manually from command line ?

Comment: I actually can't run it manually from the command line, because this code sits in a lambda function on AWS.

Comment: @OhMad What happens when you export the `auth.user` into a separate `auth_user.json`? Like explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41791442/7109869).

Comment: @GonçaloPeres when trying to export only auth.user, I get the error described here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26937