# Django tests - fixture User matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-testing, django-fixtures, django-serializer

I'm trying to run a test that loads a fixture. One the models has `GenericForeign` key to `ContentType` and a Foreign key to `auth.Users`. It associates users with content they create. I created fixture with `--natural` key (as per below) and can foreign keys resolved to names.

```
python manage.py dumpdata mtm --natural --indent=4
```

When running my tests I get the following error:

```
DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture 'fix.json': User matching query does not  exist.
```

Sample database object as dumped by manage.py:

```
{
"pk": 7, 
"model": "xx.vendor", 
"fields": {
    "phone_number": "777777777777777", 
    "alternative_phone_number": "", 
    "object_id": 1, 
    "contact_email": "", 
    "user": [
        "john"
    ], 
    "content_type": [
        "xx", 
        "axe"
    ], 
    "contact_person": "jimmy"
}
},
```

Full traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 178, in __call__
    self._pre_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 749, in _pre_setup
    self._fixture_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 881, in _fixture_setup
    'skip_validation': True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 159, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 55, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 84, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 134, in load_label
    for obj in objects:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 76, in Deserializer
    six.reraise(DeserializationError, DeserializationError(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 70, in Deserializer
    for obj in PythonDeserializer(objects, **options):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 124, in Deserializer
    obj = field.rel.to._default_manager.db_manager(db).get_by_natural_key(*field_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 167, in get_by_natural_key
    return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 151, in get
    return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 307, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name)
```

EDIT:

I have confirmed that all users referenced by vendor model exist in the db.

UPDATE 1:

My prpject uses GenericForeign key to ContentType and a Foreign key to auth.Users. I dumped the data using the --natural option but this lead to the problem described above. Now I removed the --natural option and instead dumped data for all 3 apps myApp, auth, contenttypes. When I'm running the test I get "Could not load contenttypes.ContentType(pk=50): columns app_label, model are not unique". I think this is due to the contenttypes being created dynamically when models are imported. What's the way around this?

Comment: Is this fixture also creating all the auth.User entries for you? (all the users and groups you have defined yourself)

Comment: You can exclude contenttype from fixture see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6447653/1538221

Answer (score 2):

They may exists in "the db". But do they exist in your test database? When you run tests, Django creates a [test database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database). So you'll have to dump the Users from you db and load them as fixtures too.

Fixtures are a nightmare to maintain. I advise you to use something like [model mommy](https://github.com/vandersonmota/model_mommy) or [factory boy](https://github.com/rbarrois/factory_boy) to create your fixtures at test time. Personally I like the model mommy API best, but your taste may differ.

Comment: I had a look at Model Mommy - it doesn't seem to support GenericRelations. I have moved forward on the issue and ma now facing different problem. Please see Update 1 above.